# Alter column to store the split functioned string in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I did the following:

```
df[['col1','col2']] = df.col.str.split(',', expand = True)
```

It works well for like, "a,b".
If the **col** value is a string without a comma like "a", the above line takes that string to the **col1**. But if I want to take that in the second column that is, **col2**, is there any one-line way to do that?

Note that: **I want to work it reversely only when it gets a string without a comma.**

For more clarification:
Sample dataframe column,

> col: "a,b", "a"

Expected output,

> row 1-> col1: a, col2: b

> row 2-> col1: none, col2: a

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: do you mean like this: `df[['col1','col2']] = df.col.str.split(',', expand = True).iloc[:,::-1]` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!!! It works :))

Comment: @anky but it stores all the values reversely, I mean for "a,b" col2 gets 'a' and col1 gets 'b'. But I wanted it to work reversely only for a string without comma.

Comment: You should edit your question with a dummy dataframe and an expected output, I shall reopen it.

Comment: have a look, please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use `extract`  instead of `split`:

```
df.col.str.extract(r'(\w*),?(\w+)')

   0  1
0  a  b
1     a
```

where `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a,b', 'a']})`

Note that the regex can change with respect to what is needed

EDIT:

```
 df.col.str.extract(r'^([^,]*),?(\b\w+)')

        0         1
0  Uttara     Dhaka
1          Faridpur
```

Comment: The above is working fine for that example. What will be the regex, if 'a' is city name and, 'b' is the name of state?

Comment: @AbuUbaida you will have to give examples

Comment: suppose, `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['Uttara,Dhaka', 'Faridpur']})` . I want output in this format: **row 1->** _col1: Uttara, col2: Dhaka_, **row 2->** _col1: none, col2: Faridpur_. For your convenience, you can consider **col1** and **col2** values to be city and state names respectively. So it can be any valid names. :)) Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AbuUbaida in my code above, where there is `\q` change that to `[^,]`

Comment: I am not seeing any `\q` in your code `df.col.str.extract(r'(\w*),?(\w+)')`. Did you mean `\w`? If so, this `df.col.str.extract(r'([^,]*),?([^,]+)')` is working as like the previous one. **row 2->** is showing `col1: Faridpu, col2: r` in both of the cases.

Comment: @AbuUbaida yes sorry meant to say `\w` please use  `r'^([^,]*),?([^,]+)'`

Comment: tried that also. but it's been arisen the same problem I mentioned in the earlier comment